# Labeling using 'wordwrap' and 'wrap on character' with mutiple fields in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm having a problem with multi-field labeling both using  the 'wordwrap' function and the 'wrap on character' mode. In fact I would need to use the multiline mode only on the second of the two fields (setting the wrap_lenght to optimize the number of lines) but I have not succeeded in any way.

[image]

[image]

in the first image, on the left the correct formatting, on the right the formatting that I would like to correct but avoiding too many lines as on the right in the second image. The "number" is the first field while the "name" the second field.

I tried to solve the problem using the expression:

```
"FIELD_1" || '' || wordwrap ("FIELD_2", 12)
```

without changes in formatting,
and also using a rule based labeling with:

```
"FIELD_1" || ''
'' || wordwrap ("FIELD_2", 12)
```

but completely losing the formatting.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply a condition to have more control on the labels if the length of text exceeds certain number of characters as follows:

```
 case
 when  length("Field_2") < 6 then "Field_1"  || '\n' || wordwrap("Field_2",6)
 when length("Field_2") >= 6 then "Field_1"  || '\n' || wordwrap("Field_2",12)
 end
```

The numbers 6 and 10 are just an example, you need to adjust them based on your needs.

The output should look like this:

[image]

In the above examples the length of Smith County and Bob County are different but they stacked onto two lines based on the conditions above.