# QGIS 3x label wrap line expression for individual record

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to set the text wrap for the one label only.

I prepared formula such this:

```
  CASE
  when "fid" = 12 then wordwrap (6)
  End
```

based on the thread here:

[Labeling using 'wordwrap' and 'wrap on character' with mutiple fields in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304680/labeling-using-wordwrap-and-wrap-on-character-with-mutiple-fields-in-qgis)

it doesn't work unfortunately.

I also made another attempt

```
    wordwrap(%Pschool%, 13)
```

It didn't work either. It was from the other thread below:

[Creating multiline labels in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30084/creating-multiline-labels-in-qgis)

[image]

How can I set the text wrap for an individual record?

Comment: How does your label format tab look like? Where did you enter the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
CASE
when "fid" = 12 then 6
End
```

No need for `wordwrap`, because data defined override here expects an integer input. You can see this on mousehover:

[image]